# Highlight selected row using css

Tags: html, css

How we can highlight selected row in a table using css. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tr { background: sky-blue-pink } /* Use a real colour */
tr * { background: transparent; }
```

where `tr` is a more specific selector to indicate whatever condition you have in the DOM to represent 'selected'. This will probably be a class selector: `tr.selected`

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that by "selected" you mean "hovered over by mouse":

```
tr:hover {background-color: #FF0000}
```

You could also highlight with things like 'font-weight:bold', 'color: #FF000', etc..

Comment: If you want a solid background on the whole row, you have to set border-collapse: collapse; and border-spacing: 0; on the table as well.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to do something like:

```
tr:hover { background: #FCF; }
```

See [this](http://juicystudio.com/cognitive/example16.htm) example.

Answer (score 1):

CSS part:

```
table.rowHover tr:hover{ background-color: #ccc; }

apply class = "rowHover" on the table
```

cheers !!!